# Xamarin.Forms - change size of control in code behind

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I would like to change size of a control in Xamarin.Forms with some event in code behind of a control.

Especially, I would like to change size of a StackLayout when Orientation of device changes.

For now, I have done it like this (but it does not work):

```
private void SettingsPage_OnSizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var isPortrait = UIHelpers.IsPortrait(this);
    if (isPortrait)
        RemoteServerSL.WidthRequest = RemoteServerSL.ParentView.Width;
    else
    {
        RemoteServerSL.WidthRequest = RemoteServerSL.ParentView.Width/2;
    }

    this.UpdateChildrenLayout();
    this.ForceLayout();
    RemoteServerSL.ForceLayout();

}
```

The purpose is to change Width of my StackLayout to parentWidth if I'm in landscape mode.

How can I handle that?

BTW.I'm working on Android for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use OnSizeAllocated method override to detect orientation change;

```
double previousWidth;
double previousHeight;

    protected override void OnSizeAllocated(double width, double height)
    {
        base.OnSizeAllocated(width, height);

        if (previousWidth != width || previousHeight != height)
        {
            previousWidth = width;
            previousHeight = height;

            if (width > height)
            {
                // landscape mode
            }
            else
            {
                // portrait mode
            }   
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's working fine on Page  layout. Do you have idea why it's not working for example custom StackLayout?

Comment: Can you give some details what "custom StackLayout" is?